# Juju bootstrap fails to start network on local environment

Tags: juju

I've followed the instructions at https://juju.ubuntu.com/CharmSchool and rebooted 5 times......

I cant seem to do a `juju-bootstrap` (local)
This is the output:

```
amith@amith-desktop:~$ juju bootstrap
2011-11-24 17:08:05,708 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'local' (type: local)...
2011-11-24 17:08:05,710 INFO Checking for required packages...
2011-11-24 17:08:06,593 INFO Starting networking...
error: Failed to start network default
error: internal error Child process (dnsmasq --strict-order --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/libvirt/network/default.pid --conf-file= --except-interface lo --listen-address 192.168.122.1 --dhcp-range 192.168.122.2,192.168.122.254 --dhcp-leasefile=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.leases --dhcp-lease-max=253 --dhcp-no-override) status unexpected: exit status 2

Command '['virsh', 'net-start', 'default']' returned non-zero exit status 1
2011-11-24 17:08:07,217 ERROR Command '['virsh', 'net-start', 'default']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Is there any fix at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you might already have a dns server installed on that machine which is preventing dnsmasq from binding to the needed port/interface. Dnsmasq provides dhcp/dns to the containers on the bridge network. A local caching proxy that binds to all interfaces/ports may interfere with it.